# General pattern for the series $S = x + \frac{1}{4}x^3 + \frac{9}{64} x^5 + \frac{25}{256} x^7+ \dots$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, polynomials, taylor-expansion, power-series

Is there a way to obtain the general term of the following series
$$
S = x + \frac{1}{4}x^3 + \frac{9}{64}  x^5 + \frac{25}{256}  x^7 + \frac{1225}{16384}  x^9 + \frac{3969}{65536}  x^{11} + \frac{53361}{1048576}  x^{13} + \frac{184041}{4194304}  x^{15} + \frac{41409225}{4194304}  x^{17} + \dots .
$$

What I can see is that the denominator takes initially the form of power of 4 but I cannot tell much how the pattern of the numerator evolves. Any thoughts?

Comment: Out of curiosity, where does the series come from? Cooked-up example, or did it arise while solving another problem?

Comment: @user170231 from a physical problem involving a self-propelled surfer moving on a 2D plane. There are other series that I need to figure out myself...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When presented with a sequence of integers (like $1,9,25,1225,3969,53361,\ldots$) a fantastic first idea is to consult the [Online Encyclopedia of Integer Sequences](https://oeis.org/). In particular, we can search the OEIS for your sequence, and we find it agrees with [A038534](https://oeis.org/A038534), the "Numerators of the Coefficients of EllipticK/Pi".

In this post there are references to formulas for these numbers, as well as places in the literature where they have occurred.

---

I hope this helps ^_^

Comment: Impressive. Thanks. https://oeis.org/A038533 for the denominator: Denominator of coefficients of both EllipticK/Pi and EllipticE/Pi. Very much appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

The numerators are numerators of the hypergeometric series ${}_{2}F_{1}(1/2,1/2;1;x)$.

Comment: Thanks. Mmm this does seem to work. I would expect 0.5365910036 for $x = 0.5$