# What is the function whose Maclaurin series is given by $1 + \frac{3}{4} \, x^2 + \frac{75}{128} \, x^4 + \frac{245}{512} \, x^6 + \dots$?

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, taylor-expansion, power-series, special-functions

Let
$$
f(x) = 1 + \frac{3}{4} \, x^2 + \frac{75}{128} \, x^4 + \frac{245}{512} \, x^6 + \frac{6615}{16384} \, x^8 + \frac{22869}{65536} \, x^{10} \\+ \frac{1288287}{4194304} \, x^{12} + \frac{4601025}{16777216} \, x^{14} + \dots
$$

Does $f(x)$ correspond to any combination of known functions?

> I understand that this question bears similarity to the [one](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4731034/general-pattern-for-the-series-s-x-frac14x3-frac964-x5-fra) I posed yesterday; however, despite my diligent efforts, I have been unable to discover any combination of elliptic functions or their derivatives that align with the coefficients of this particular series.

Comment: https://oeis.org/A189805 You were suggested to look at OEIS before. Did you try it this time?

Comment: @Gary Thanks for the reference. Yes, I did. But I didn't find what I was looking for.

Comment: It's the only sequence that shows up when typing the first four or five numerators... Did you perhaps input zeroes instead of only inputting the nonzero terms? Or maybe you used commas instead of semicolons (I don't know if that has an impact though)?

Comment: @BrunoB Thanks for pointing out the search funktion which I wasn't aware of. I was simply looking at the crossref series and searches for the one that matches mine. I know now how to proceed in future searches!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's the Maclaurin series of the function
$$
f(x)=\frac{16}{\pi}\frac{(2-x^2)K(x^2)-2E(x^2)}{x^4},
$$
where $K$ and $E$ are the complete elliptic integrals of the first and second kind, respectively. See [here](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=taylor+series+16%2Fpi*%28%282-x%5E2%29EllipticK%5Bx%5E2%5D-2EllipticE%5Bx%5E2%5D%29%2Fx%5E4).

Comment: Thanks for the answer. It is strange that Maple does not provide the correction series expansion of this function!

Comment: @preuss Some references call $K(x)$ what Wolfram calls $K(x^2)$. Same with $E$. You should check the definition that Maple uses.

Comment: @Gary and Gonçalo, could you explain how you found that function ?

Comment: @Gary Indeed. All works fine now. Thanks for pointing this out!

Comment: Gonçalo, where did you find the line “*MATHEMATICA Numerator[CoefficientList[Series[((2-m)EllipticK[m]-2EllipticE[m])/m, {m, 0, 20}]/Pi, m]]*” ? There is not that line in the OEIS link you gave me.

Comment: Gonçalo, I used your link, but I believed you had already put the numerators of the series. Anyway, in the following link there are the numerators and consequently it appears the line containing the function. [OEIS](https://oeis.org/search?q=1%2C3%2C75%2C245%2C6615%2C22869%2C1288287%2C4601025&language=english&go=Search)

Comment: Gonçalo, do you know how the OEIS website manages to find the function correctly ?